# How can you reference an annotation in a Javadoc?

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc

How can you reference an annotation as a code snippet properly in Javadoc?

For example:

```
<code>
  @Annotation public String field = "";
</code>
```

The @Annotation gets treated as an unrecognized Javadoc tag rather than a code snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC,

```
<code>
  &#64;Annotation public String field = "";
</code>
```

Or, I believe,

```
{@code 
  @Annotation public String field = "";
}
```

Comment: I didn't find that the second one worked, but the first option does work.